# Macports, mpif90, error "Attempting to use an MPI routine before initializing MPICH"

Tags: macos, macports, macos-mojave

I have installaed via macports openmpi and mpich. The fortran code compiles well but during run time gives an error saying "Attempting to use an MPI routine before initializing MPICH".

Mine is masOS Mojave 10.14.5.

Answer (score 0):

`brew` is more robust these days.

Try

```
brew install openmpi
```

Then

```
mpirun -np 4 <some task>
```

should run with no issue